# Finding the limit of $f$ given $f(0)>0, f(x) \leq f'(x).$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function, with $f(0) > 0$, so $f(x) \leq f'(x)$.

Prove that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } f(x)=\infty.$$

I tried to use lagrange, but this doesn't lead me to the conclusion.

Comment: $f>0$ and $f'\ge f$ imply that $(\log(f(x)))'\ge 1$.  Integrating yields $f(x)\ge f(0)e^x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y = e^x$ is a solution to the ODE $y(x) = y'(x)$.

We know that $f(x) \leq f'(x)$, so hopefully we should be able to prove that $f(x)$ grows faster than $e^x$. This will be sufficient to show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^x = \infty$.

So let us define a new function $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by
$$ g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{e^{x}}.$$

Note that $g$ is differentiable (Why?), and 
$$ g'(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{e^{x}} - \frac{f(x)}{e^{x}} \geq 0.$$
Therefore, $g$ is an increasing function.

Can you finish off from here?

Comment: No . Can you please, finish it?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on where to go from here?

Comment: For example, $g$ being an increasing function means that $x >  0 \implies g(x) \geq g(0)$. Can you turn this into an inequality for $f(x)$?

Comment: I tried to use monotony

Comment: I did this, but ir implies that f(x)>0

Comment: Well $g(x) = f(x)e^{-x}$. And $g(0) = f(0)$. So...

Comment: But f(0)>0. How can I prove that f(x)> smth with limit infinit

Comment: Okay, we've shown that $x > 0 \implies f(x) \geq f(0)e^{x}$. Do you agree?

Comment: O, yeah, stupid me. It's obvious from here

Comment: By the way, do you understand the intuition behind wanting to consider $g(x) = f(x)/e^{x}$? As in, how you would think of trying this?

Comment: Yes, I understand this

Answer (score 2):

From $f(0)>0$ and $f'(0)\geq f(0)>0$, we get $f'(0)\geq0$. If $f$ is ever going to decrease, we need a maximum $c$ with $f'(c)=0$; but then we would have $f(c)\leq0$, which is impossible. It follows that $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x$.

So $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists, either as a number or $\infty$. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L<\infty$, this implies that, eventually, $f'(x)>L/2$. So, for $x$ big enough, 
$$
f(x)-f(x-1)=\int_{x-1}^xf'(t)\,dt>\frac L2,
$$
contradicting the existence of the limit of $f$. So the only possibility is that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: The OP said $f(0) > 0$

Comment: Yes. It doesn't change the argument, though.

Comment: It's unclear to me why $f(c)\leq0$ is impossible, also why the set of $c$ having $f'(c)=0$ has to have a maximum - I'm not saying it isn't true, just it is not obvious.

Comment: I never said that the set of zeroes of $f'$ has a maximum. In fact, it is empty.  The function cannot take negative values because for that it has to "turn down". To start going down, it first has to stop going up, so you need $f'(c)=0$; the inequality $f'(c)\geq f(c)$ then implies that $f$ is zero or negative to the left of $c$, which contradicts the fact that $f$ started positive and was increasing.

Comment: I prefer this to the shorter/tricky answer involving $e^{-x} f(x) $ because it uses the simple theorems of calculus. +1